# Is it possible for meteors and asteriods to become natural satellites of Earth?

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, earth, asteroids, meteors

We know that the moon isn't falling on the earth because it's in orbit. If we make an asteriod or meteor spin is it possible for it to become a natural satellite of Earth?

Comment: did you mean spin around earth or about its own axis?

Comment: Yes. This is [a proposed origin for Mars's moon Phobos](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0004-637X/777/2/127).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is asking whether it's possible for an asteroid to be *naturally* captured and put into orbit around the earth, the answer is "yes".  But it requires a very specific set of conditions.

The incoming asteroid would need to be deflected by the Moon into a direction and speed that corresponds to an orbital trajectory.  That means that its speed, the distance by which it misses the moon, and the angle of its approach relative to the Moon's direction of motion, would all have to fit within specific ranges. The vast majority of approach trajectories would result in the asteroid just flying by with its final trajectory altered by interactions with the Earth and Moon.

Most likely a captured asteroid would be thrown into a highly elongated elliptical orbit around the Earth, but then it would interact with the Moon every time it looped around the Earth -- so the orbit would change.  It could simply be tossed away into an escape trajectory, or into a trajectory that hits the Earth.  For it to end up in a relatively *stable* orbit, it would need to survive multiple interactions with the Moon and end up in that stable orbit.  So, requiring a *stable* orbit further narrows down the range of possible approach trajectories.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what you mean by spinning ( i.e., the revolve
 about the earth or rotate about it's own axis). But for the rest of the question yes anything (artificial or natural) can be made a satellite of earth as long as it has a velocity $v = \sqrt {G \frac {M_{earth}}{R_{orbit}}}$. ( Also it's direction of motion should be such that it doesn't crash into the earth ().

Answer (score -2):

The moon itself was an asteroid that became natural satellite of Earth.

As for 'spin' in the case of the moon, the periods of spinning around the moon's axis and spinning around the earth are the same as one month. That is why we only see one side of the moon. The dark side of the moon is usually concealed from the public (unless you are Pink Floyd), just like DT's tax return record.